# Transformation into quadratic program

Tags: optimization, quadratic-programming

I am struggling with the following optimization problem:

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
& \underset{x_{1}, \ ..., \ x_{5} \in \mathrm{R}}{\text{minimize}}
& & \begin{pmatrix}
x_{1} + x_{2} \\
x_{1} x_{2} \\
x_{3} \\
x_{4} \\
x_{5}
\end{pmatrix}^{\textbf{T}}  \textbf{A}  \begin{pmatrix}
x_{1} + x_{2} \\
x_{1} x_{2} \\
x_{3} \\
x_{4} \\
x_{5}
\end{pmatrix} + \textbf{B}^{\textbf{T}}
 \begin{pmatrix}
x_{1} + x_{2} \\
x_{1} x_{2} \\
x_{3} \\
x_{4} \\
x_{5}
\end{pmatrix}
\\
& \text{subject to}
& & x_{1} \geq k \text{ and } x_{2} \geq k
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
the matrix **A** is invertible.

My attemp:
I introduce two artificial decision variables $x_{1}' = x_{1} + x_{2}$ and $x_{2}' = x_{1}x_{2}$ and I solve the  quadratic programming problem:

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
& \underset{x_{1}', \ x_{2}', \ x_{3}, \ ..., \ x_{5} \in \mathrm{R}}{\text{minimize}}
& & \begin{pmatrix}
x_{1}'\\
x_{2}' \\
x_{3} \\
x_{4} \\
x_{5}
\end{pmatrix}^{\textbf{T}}  \textbf{A}  \begin{pmatrix}
x_{1}' \\
x_{2}' \\
x_{3} \\
x_{4} \\
x_{5}
\end{pmatrix} + \textbf{B}^{\textbf{T}}
 \begin{pmatrix}
x_{1}' \\
x_{2}' \\
x_{3} \\
x_{4} \\
x_{5}
\end{pmatrix}
\\
& \text{subject to}
& & x_{1}' \geq 2k \text{ and } x_{2}' \geq k^{2}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

Unfortunatlly, it produces wrong results since
\begin{equation*}
\left\{
\begin{array}{r c l}
x_{1}' & \geq & 2k\\
x_{2}' & \geq & k^{2}
\end{array}
\right.
\text{ does not imply }
\left\{
\begin{array}{r c l}
x_{1} & \geq & k\\
x_{2} & \geq & k
\end{array}
\right.
\end{equation*}
So, is it possible to overcome this issue? or am I investigating the wrong way?

Comment: Try Quadratic Constrained Quadratic Programming https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratically_constrained_quadratic_program    http://www.mit.edu/~parrilo/cdc03_workshop/03_qcqp_2003_12_07_01_screen.pdf  The $x_1'$ and $x_2'$ equations are part of the quadratic contraints.